# Is it possible to select locale in box-api authentication?

Tags: authentication, box-api

Can I explicit select a language when redirecting a user to the authentication page via API?

Answer (score 0):

The auth page will detect what region the user is coming from, and localize appropriately if we support the language of that region. There isn't currently a way to force which way this will appear, except for spoofing the location of where the user is coming from.

Comment: And if I'm at a foreign country? I can't change the language. I think it's ok to detect user region and language but I would offer the chance to change it, just in case.